# Why isnt cypress honoring my timeout for a single command?

Tags: cypress, timeout

I'm a couple of weeks into cypress test automation (cypress V12) and while it seems cool I am confused by what I am seeing.

I have code that looks like this:

```
    it('shows the problem for Stack Overflow', {defaultCommandTimeout: 20000}, function () {
      //bunch of commands that do stuff are here but I dont think they are related to the issue...

      const loadingSpinnerLocator = ".k-loader-canvas";
      cy.get(loadingSpinnerLocator).should('be.visible');
      cy.get(loadingSpinnerLocator).should('not.exist' ,{ timeout: 15000 });          

    })
```

this code works fine because I am doing a workaround in the top line and overriding the defaultCommandTimeout to 20 seconds.

If I remove the override on the "it statement" the test fails when we are making sure that the spinner is gone after 4 seconds.  Isn't my code saying to look for 15 seconds???

**How do I tell cypress to "wait up to 15 seconds for the loading spinner to not be there" without bumping up the timeout for the whole test??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, `{ timeout: 15000 }` is an **options** object.

All Cypress commands are documented with a **Syntax** section which tells you if you can pass **options**, for example [.should()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should)

> **Syntax**
>
> ```js
> .should(chainers)
> .should(chainers, value)
> .should(chainers, method, value)
> .should(callbackFn)
> ```

This tells you there is no options syntax for `.should()`.

On the other hand for [.get()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get), there are permutations that allow an `options` parameter,

> **Syntax**
>
> ```js
> cy.get(selector)
> cy.get(alias)
> cy.get(selector, options)
> cy.get(alias, options)
> ```